# как сделать так чтобы граница уходила внутрь блока?

Tags: html, css

есть ссылка, сделанная с помощью пэдинга. хочу чтобы при наведении на нее курсором граница увеличивалась на пиксель, но это происходит "наружу", увеличивая само пространство, занимаемое ссылкой. как исправить?

прим

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

прописано.
сама ссылка:

```html
<a class="intro-button" href="">see our work</a>
```

```css
.intro-button {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px 17px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.intro-button:hover {
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уменьшайте внутренние отступы при наведении (изменил цвет границы, чтобы было видно)

```css
.intro-button {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px 17px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.intro-button:hover {
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid red;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}
```

```html
<a class="intro-button" href="">see our work</a>
```

Comment: cпасибо большое!

Comment: @DzenisenkaFiodar отметьте ответ как правильный, если он вам помог

Comment: может еще на один вопрос по схожей теме можете дать ответ? У меня есть блок с текстом, для которого мне нужно использовать border-bottom, но подчеркнуть не всю нижнюю границу, а лишь пару центральных букв. (например в слове "выполнить" нужно чтобы граница была лишь под "олн". как это реализовать?...

Comment: @DzenisenkaFiodar для этого выделите необходимые буквы в отдельный тег и используйте свойство **text-decoration: underline;**

**<p>вып<span>олн<span>ить</p>**